# How to get face tracking working with the new Realsense SDK2 and openCV in Visual Studio?

Tags: opencv, sdk, realsense

I was wondering if anyone has gotten face tracking working with the new Realsense SDK2 and OpenCV.

Comment: This is not the type of question we answer here – make an attempt at getting it working yourself, then show us what you have tried and where you have failed.

Comment: I have attempted. I have the realsense2 lib merged with openCV. Everything builds fine. When I try and run the program the Realsense d415 flickers on for about 2 seconds then turns off. Here is some code.

Comment: Nvm, There is not enough room for my code.

Comment: Without seeing your code, helping you is going to be difficult. Please add some details to your question, try to reduce your code to the bare minimum necessary to show the problem, and post it here.

Comment: I will form a new question will code pictures. I was also wondering if anyone has even got it to work, or is this forum only for help not discussion?

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code, post the actual code instead. This is not a forum, and questions are not meant to start a discussion but to find the solution to a specific problem. Find more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/help